# AWS OpsWorks Error: Supervisor service cannot be restarted because it does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, supervisord, aws-opsworks

I have two recipe in my AWS OpsWorks custom cookbook

First one is `myserver/recipes/supervisor.rb`

```
 #myserver::supervisor

 supervisor_service "mylistener" do
      command "/usr/bin/php /var/www/listener.php"
      autostart true
      autorestart true
      numprocs 1
      process_name "%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s"
 end
```

and the second one is `myserver/recipes/update_code.rb`

```
 #myserver::update_code
 include_recipe "myserver::supervisor"
 execute "update_code" do
     command %Q {
         /usr/local/bin/downloadfile.sh
         /usr/local/bin/changelink.sh
     }
     notifies :restart, "supervisor_service[mylistener]"
 end
```

The `supervisor_service` is provided from [here](https://github.com/poise/supervisor).

At first I tried executing the first recipe in running instances. The execution succeeded and the supervisor was running smoothly.

The second recipe is basically updating the code run by the supervisor. So I need to restart the supervisor. But the then I got this error everytime I executed the service.

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `restart` on resource 'supervisor_service[mylistener]'
================================================================================


RuntimeError
------------
Supervisor service mylistener cannot be restarted because it does not exist


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20140116091718_218/site-cookbooks/myserver/recipes/supervisor.rb

9: supervisor_service "mylistener" do
10:     command "/usr/bin/php /var/www/listener.php"
11:     autostart true
12:     autorestart true
13:     numprocs 1
14:     process_name "%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s"
15: end
```

What am I doing wrong?

### **UPDATE**

I put `include_recipe 'supervisor'` in the file `myserver/recipes/supervisor.rb`.

```
#myserver::supervisor
include_recipe 'supervisor'

supervisor_service "mylistener" do
    command "/usr/bin/php /var/www/listener.php"
    autostart true
    autorestart true
    numprocs 1
    process_name "%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s"
end
```

But when I execute `myserver::update_code` in my AWS OpsWorks, it still returns error below, but with a new section `Compiled Resource`.

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `restart` on resource 'supervisor_service[mylistener]'
================================================================================


RuntimeError
------------
Supervisor service mylistener cannot be restarted because it does not exist


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20140116091718_218/site-cookbooks/myrecipe/recipes/supervisor.rb

11: supervisor_service "mylistener" do
12:     command "/usr/bin/php /var/www/listener.php"
13:     autostart true
14:     autorestart true
15:     numprocs 1
16:     process_name "%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s"
17: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20140116091718_218/site-cookbooks/myserver/recipes/supervisor.rb:11:in `from_file'

supervisor_service("mylistener") do
priority 999
numprocs_start 0
autorestart true
retries 0
updated true
stderr_capture_maxbytes "0"
exitcodes [0, 2]
stderr_logfile "/var/log/mylistener.err.log"
cookbook_name :myserver
stdout_capture_maxbytes "0"
autostart true
recipe_name "supervisor"
serverurl "AUTO"
action :enable
stderr_logfile_backups 10
startretries 3
process_name "%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s"
stdout_logfile_backups 10
stopwaitsecs 10
stderr_logfile_maxbytes "50MB"
startsecs 1
numprocs 1
retry_delay 2
stdout_logfile_maxbytes "50MB"
command "/usr/bin/php /var/www/listener.php"
stopsignal :TERM
service_name "mylistener"
stdout_logfile "/var/log/mylistener.out.log"
end
```

**UPDATE**

I finally use this manual execution

```
execute "supervisor-restart-mylistener" do
    command "supervisorctl restart mylistener:*"
end
```

But still trying to figure out why the `notifies` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error but it was due to a bug in the supervisor cookbook.
https://github.com/poise/supervisor/issues/43

I reverted back to the Supervisor cookbook 0.4.2 and it works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're including both of those recipes in the run_list or using `include_recipe`, this error is correct. If `update_code.rb` notifies `supervisor_service`, then the `supervisor.rb` recipe is a "dependency" of that recipe. You should add the following to the top of your `update_code.rb`:

```
include_recipe 'myserver::supervisor'
```

Comment: you mean `include_recipe 'supervisor'` ? or should I just put that in the recipe `myserver::supervisor`?

Comment: i updated the code. i'm new to chef (and opsworks), bear with me.

Comment: Have you enabled the service?

Comment: I don't really know what that means, but when I first time executed `supervisor` and `myserver::supervisor`, the `supervisord` service shows up and the program `mylistener` is also running. So I think yes it is enabled.